# Why does 'functools.cache' and 'functools.lru_cache' not working for inner function inside class method?

Tags: python, functools

Why are `functools.cache` and `functools.lru_cache` not working for an inner function inside a class method? Are there any workaround without installing 3rd-party packages and without moving the inner function somewhere to the outer scope?

```py
from functools import cache

class Sample:

    def outer(self, a):
        @cache
        def inner(b):
            print(f"Inner function is called! b: '{b}'")
            return b

        return inner(a)


sample = Sample()
sample.outer(100)
sample.outer(100)
sample.outer(100)
```

Output:

```
Inner function is called! b: '100'
Inner function is called! b: '100'
Inner function is called! b: '100'
```

I want the inner function to be called only once for the same argument.

Comment: They _are_ working, but the cache is applied to the specific instance of the `inner` function and every time you call `outer` you get a new instance.

Comment: @jonrsharpe When I am adding `print(repr(inner))` inside `outer` function, I always see something like `<functools._lru_cache_wrapper object at 0x7f3238519790>` **on every call**. If the inner function is recreated, why does it still points to the same object in memory on every `outer` call?

Comment: The memory address is the same because the object is immediately garbage-collected and then the same address is allocated to the next object. Objects' ids (memory addresses in CPython) are only guaranteed to be unique for the lifetime of the object; two objects whose lifetimes do not overlap can have the same id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably the `inner` function gets "re-created" every time `outer` is called, causing the caching to no longer work. This is corroborated by this example, which calls `inner` multiple times from `outer`:

```py
from functools import cache

class Sample:

    def outer(self, a):
        @cache
        def inner(b):
            print(f"Inner function is called! b: '{b}'")
            return b

        for i in range(3):
            print(f"Inner call #{i}")
            print(inner(a))
        return 

sample = Sample()
sample.outer(100)
sample.outer(100)
sample.outer(100)
```

Which outputs:

```
Inner call #0
Inner function is called! b: '100'
100
Inner call #1
100
Inner call #2
100
Inner call #0
Inner function is called! b: '100'
100
Inner call #1
100
Inner call #2
100
Inner call #0
Inner function is called! b: '100'
100
Inner call #1
100
Inner call #2
100
```

So, the caching *does* work, but only until the `inner` class is "re-created". A very simple solution is to avoid using an inner function, but relying on a static the following:

```py
from functools import cache

class Sample:

    @staticmethod
    @cache
    def _inner(b):
        print(f"Inner function is called! b: '{b}'")
        return b

    def outer(self, a):
        for i in range(3):
            print(f"Inner call #{i}")
            print(Sample._inner(a))
        return 

sample = Sample()
sample.outer(100)
sample.outer(100)
sample.outer(100)
```

Note that I've renamed `inner` to `_inner`, to indicate that `_inner` is not meant to be exposed to users of your class. Furthermore, I've turned it into a static method. This allows you to use `Sample._inner(...)` rather than `self._inner(...)`. After all, the `self` parameter isn't used in `_inner`, so it can be a static function.

This outputs (the desired):

```py
Inner call #0
Inner function is called! b: '100'
100
Inner call #1
100
Inner call #2
100
Inner call #0
100
Inner call #1
100
Inner call #2
100
Inner call #0
100
Inner call #1
100
Inner call #2
100
```

Which indicates that everything was cached properly for the different `outer` calls.

Comment: If the inner function is recreated, why does it always point to the same object in memory? I mean that if you will print `repr(inner)` on every call, it is always the same object. Or I understand "recreation" in a wrong way?

Comment: I'm unsure why this "re-creation" as I've just informally called it now causes this behaviour. All I know is that this is the behaviour that seems to happen. One hypothesis is that the `inner` object is just cleared from memory once the `outer` function returns, as the `outer` scope is the only place where this `inner` function should exist. Then, when it's created again, this obviously has no "memory" of a potential previous function that was there.